# Quick way to calculate dimension in inch for photos in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I have around 1000 photos that I need to calculate their dimensions from pixels to inches. For a few photos I used [an online pixels to inch converter like this](http://www.ninjaunits.com/convert-pixels-inches/). But for 1000 photos i will kill myself if I need to manually check and calculate their dimensions. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: pictures don't really have any inches or centimetres when they are still on your pc. It only matters when you're printing them. So I'm not entirely sure what the issue is.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341930/pixel-to-centimeter

Answer (score 0):

Using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) you could get pixel size and DPI using this command:

```
  identify -format "%w x %h %x x %y\n" image.jpg
```

where:

```
  %x x resolution (density) 
  %y y resolution (density)
  %w current width in pixels
  %h current image height in pixels
```

this command will print:

```
  216 x 144 72 PixelsPerInch x 72 PixelsPerInch
```

If your images have same DPI, you could get images size in inch using this command:

```
  cd /path/where/are/your/images
  while read imageFile; do echo $imageFile; identify -format "%[fx:w/72] by %[fx:h/72] inches" $imageFile; done < <(ls)
```

that should print filename and its inch dimension for each image in `/path/where/are/your/images` folder.

Some useful link: [ImageMagick escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) and [Determining DPI through ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16110)